# Google Chart - Tooltips not showing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw multiple charts on the same webpage.

I create them with the following code :

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': chartType, 
    'containerId': $scope.arrayDiv[i].id,
    ... 
});

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
//Filling the DataTable

chart.setDataTable(data);
chart.draw();
```

I use a ng-repeat to display all the div contained in $scope.arrayDiv. It's working, but the tooltips are not displaying.

I read here that the issue come from the fact that I'm using the draw() method.

However, i tried creating a single  (outside of the ng-repeat) and drawing a chart in it with the same code, and the tooltips were displaying correctly.

What's the source of the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Turn out the issue was in the CSS : when the `position` attribute is set to any value, the tooltips aren't displaying. Not sure why though.